# How many concurrent action cable connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, actioncable

I've set up ActionCable in a staging environment and things look fine so far. Following the instructions [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/) I set the `passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process` to `0` to address this problem:

> Passenger's highly optimized load balancer assumes that Ruby apps can handle 1 (or thread-limited amount of) concurrent connection(s). This is usually the case and results in optimal load-balancing. But endpoints that deal with SSE/Websockets can handle many more concurrent connections, so the assumption leads to degraded performance.

My question is how can I now compute the maximum amount of connections my app can handle. Passenger suggests that:

> A value of 0 means that each process can handle an unlimited number of
>   connections.

Obviously there is an upper bound here, I'm just not sure how I can find it other than empirical testing.

Comment: There's no specific software limitation. Empirical testing is the answer. Maybe you're running this on a peanut, or maybe you're running it on a machine with 256 cores. We have no idea.

Comment: @tadman That's a valid point, but given some numbers (e.g. 8Gb of memory, 2 CPUs, etc.), is your point there is still not way for me to come up with an estimate it always will have to be done empirically?

Comment: Remember idle connections use almost zero resources, while one that's slamming the network connection can potentially monopolize a CPU core. You'll need to do some testing here under *simulated real-world conditions* to find out. This is like asking "How fast can a car go?" It *depends*.